# Tracking object Access in C

Tags: c

Are there any efficient ways of tracking data accesses (I am interested in dynamically allocated data) in C ? I want to track what objects have been accessed, and keep a count their access frequency.

Comment: In pure C without an additional indirection layer on top of pointers? No.

Comment: I meant dynamically allocated data.  Edited the question.

Comment: Do you mean something like "Count how many times this particular 'object' has been accessed in the last 5 minutes" or "Is there still a reference to this object"? The two are somewhat different (although neither is easily solved).

Comment: I am interested in keeping a count on how many times an object has been accessed.

Comment: @BЈовић In C standard parlance, everything that's not a function is an object. `int a;` - here `a` is an object.

Answer (score 1):

You could use techniques employed by tools like [Electric Fence](http://linux.die.net/man/3/efence) to track memory access. However, those techniques are costly in terms of CPU and/or memory (with a trade-off between the two).

P.S. To be honest, the question sounds like there might be a bit of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) going on. Perhaps if you elaborated on what it is that you are *actually* trying to achieve, and settled on *one* programming language, this might lead to more useful answers.

Comment: I have updated the question. Protection based solutions such as mprotect are there that can be used, however, they are extremely costly in terms of CPU cycles. Thanks.